# How to use Windsor IoC in ASP.net Core 2

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0, castle-windsor, ioc-container

How can I use Castle Windsor as an IOC instead of the default .net core IOC container?

I have built a service resolver that depends on `WindsorContainer` to resolve services.

Something like:

```
public class ServiceResolver
{
    private static WindsorContainer container;
    public ServiceResolver()
    {
        container = new WindsorContainer();
        // a method to register components in container
        RegisterComponents(container);
    }

    public IList<T> ResolveAll<T>()
    {
        return container.ResolveAll<T>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Can not figure out how to let my .net core 2 web API use this resolver as a replacement for IServiceCollection.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For others Reference In addition to the solution Nkosi provided.

There is a nuget package called [Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection/) that will provide you with the following method:

```
WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider(WindsorContainer,IServiceCollection);
```

Which's returned type is `IServiceProvider` and you will not need to create you own wrapper.

So the solution will be like:

```
public class ServiceResolver{    
    private static WindsorContainer container;
    private static IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public ServiceResolver(IServiceCollection services) {
        container = new WindsorContainer();
        //Register your components in container
        //then
        serviceProvider = WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider(container, services);
    }

    public IServiceProvider GetServiceProvider() {
        return serviceProvider;
    }    
}
```

and in *Startup*...

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMvc();
    // Add other framework services

    // Add custom provider
    var container = new ServiceResolver(services).GetServiceProvider();
    return container;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

For .net core, which centers DI around the `IServiceProvider`, you would need to create you own wrapper

Reference : [Introduction to Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core: Replacing the default services container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#replacing-the-default-services-container)

```
public class ServiceResolver : IServiceProvider {
    private static WindsorContainer container;

    public ServiceResolver(IServiceCollection services) {
        container = new WindsorContainer();
        // a method to register components in container
        RegisterComponents(container, services);
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType) {
        return container.Resolve(serviceType);
    }

    //...
}
```

and then configure the container in `ConfigureServices` and return an `IServiceProvider`:

> When using a third-party DI container, you must change `ConfigureServices` so that it returns `IServiceProvider` instead of `void`.

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMvc();
    // Add other framework services

    // Add custom provider
    var container = new ServiceResolver(services);
    return container;
}
```

At runtime, your container will be used to resolve types and inject dependencies.

Comment: I have done as your guild but came following error: Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: 'No component for supporting the service Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHostOptions was found'

Comment: And I wanted to know where the controller injections comes to play ?

Answer (score 12):

**This answer is for .NET Core 2 only**

There is an official Castle Windsor support for ASP.NET Core which has been released as version 5 (get it from nuget [Castle.Windsor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.Windsor), [Castle.Facilities.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.Facilities.AspNetCore)). The documentation how to use it is [here](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/aspnetcore-facility.md).

More info in the related issues [here](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/issues/393) and [here](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/issues/418)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add that answer Yahya Hussein offers works for me, however I had to adjust my scope to `LifestyleCustome<MsScopedLifestyleManager>()` on each dependency I registered.

This may be second nature to some but it took me a minute to figure out.