# Is there a way to use MS Dependency Injection with Castle windor

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Is there a way to use MS Dependency Injection with Castle Windsor.

I am trying to use a third party library and unfortunately they only support MS Dependency Injection installation.
(https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/opentracing-integration.html#installation)

It's not feasible for us move our entire codebase MS Dependency injection, so I am wondering if there is a way to do both.

Comment: examine this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672614/how-to-use-windsor-ioc-in-asp-net-core-2

Comment: have you made it work? I tried and now I get missing assembly reference, somehow Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection throws the error "Could not load file or assembly 'Castle.Windsor, Version=4.0.0.0"